# Increase the font size for a map label

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I have this code below that creates a map of a shapefile:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pm10_base = gpd.read_file('/Users/jacob/Desktop/MSthesis/wrfpy/actual/mmshp/population_by_lgu.shp')






# set the value column that will be visualised
variable = 'NAME_2'

# create figure and axes for Matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(8, 10))
# remove the axis
ax.axis('off')
# add a title and annotation
ax.set_title('Metro Manila LGU Division ', fontdict={'fontsize': '20', 'fontweight' : '4'})

# create map
pm10_base.plot(column='NAME_2', alpha= 0.9, linewidth=0.02, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')


# Add Labels
pm10_base['coords'] = pm10_base['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.representative_point().coords[:])
pm10_base['coords'] = [coords[0] for coords in pm10_base['coords']]
for idx, row in pm10_base.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(s=row['NAME_2'], xy=row['coords'],horizontalalignment='center', )



plt.savefig('/Users/jacob/Desktop/figure312.png', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

Everything else is okay;however, I want to make the name of the cities larger.

What can I do to increase the font size of the city names as seen in the output of this code below?

Any hel would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with this a lot,
but wasn't there a `size` parameter for `.annotate`?

Something like this:

`plt.annotate(s=row['NAME_2'], xy=row['coords'], horizontalalignment='center', size=99, )`